# "Don't you know" in upper class-British?

Tags: british-english

I have been reading Jeeves and Wooster recently, and the latter character says "don't you know" a hell of a lot. Eg. "He's my manservant, don't you know?" "Tea is very good after a journey, don't you know?"

I am interested in the origin of this phrase. I'm sure it is upper-class British but Googling this gives me no information.

Comment: It is a very dated way of speaking, and was probably only ever particular to certain people. It may have been a "marker" used to convey that the speaker had a presumptuous air about him/or her, found more in fiction than in reality. I'm not sure if a character like Lady Bracknell in Wilde's *Importance of Being Earnest* would have used it

Comment: It's the 20's upper-class-twit version of contemporary teen "Tea's like youknow really good after a journey". *Youknow* is pronounced with the stress on *you-* and a falling tone.

Comment: Not only is it dated, but wasn't Wodehouse also famous for poking fun at  upper class twits such as Bertram Wooster and their mannerisms? They may not have existed in the profusion that fiction/film/TV-series would have us believe, if I may permit myself a statement of moderate sweepingness.

Comment: It's not really all THAT dated, though I haven't heard it in years.  It's simply an idiom that has the same meaning as "you know" in the same place -- a sort of emphasizer of the preceding statement.  I'm sure I've known people in the US who commonly used it.

Comment: (And one needs to remember that Wodehouse did the vast majority of his writing in the US.)

Comment: (I'm thinking that Francis McDormand, in her role in Fargo, affected the use of "don'cha know" in her performance.  If not her in that role then a very similar personality in a similar role.)

Comment: I guess it sounds familiar because it's supposed to be a Minnesotaism: http://minnesota.cbslocal.com/2014/07/14/10-minnesota-words-phrases-asg-visitors-should-know/  (Though it's not something I commonly hear around here in Tropical Southern Minnesota.)

Comment: @HotLicks -I'm just over and up a bit from you, in the WI Northwoods, and we use it with an inflected question mark, eg. "We were so tired from shopping, y'know(?) so we decided to stop for tea." I'm guilty of sprinkling those all over the place. A little further north in the UP it's "eh," but with and without the inferred ? and maybe more often at the end of a statement. "This tea really needs some honey, eh."

Comment: @HotLicks - Fun link ya got there dontcha know!

Comment: @W9WBH - I always knew Wisconsinites were weird, but *tea*?  With *honey*??

Comment: This construction is sometimes called a "tag question".  A tag question is a declarative statement that has been turned into a question (often a rhetorical one) by adding a tag word or phrase at the end. Other examples include "...right?" and "...huh?"

Comment: @HotLicks - I know, right? (NYC and I'm sure elsewhere) Yah, and I don't actually "do" tea lol.

Answer (score 1):

'Don't you know?' or the variant 'don't you see?' dates at least from the late 19th Century--and it is irritating. My grandfather would make what he thought was a profound statement and then tack on the condescending 'don't you see?' as if his wisdom had fallen on the uncomprehending ears of an idiot.

Comment: It would be instructive to tell us your grandfather's linguistic/cultural heritage.

Comment: Perhaps it had :-)

Comment: I don't know your grandfather of course; but I have to disagree in that I don't think, in its common usage at least, that any condescension is intended.